# How to configure registration/logIn into a existing project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication

My project already has the Identity Folder:

[image]

And the database already has the roles tables :

[image]

How do I configure LogIn and registeration from here? Is there any tutorial that I can follow. Most of them explain how to do this from the beginig, but I'm having a hard time implementing this into my project.
(Besides the files that the images show, I also have the LoginPartial View, but that's it)
Here is my StartUp class:

```
  public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );
        services.AddSignalR();

      

        
        services.AddTransient<IgnicoesAPIController, IgnicoesAPIController>();
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();

    

        String caminho = Configuration["AppSettings:Servidor"] + "/myHub";

        //endpoints.MapHub<MyHub>(caminho);
        //app.UseSignalR(route =>
        //{
        //    route.MapHub<MyHub>(caminho);

        //});

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<MyHub>("/myHub");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
               pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            

        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) about scaffold Identity,and maybe you can create Scaffold Identity into an empty project,and see the login and register code in the project.It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which route you want to take from this point. If you wish to create razor page or view with controller. Either way you will probably use ‘SigninManager’ or ‘UserManager’, thats built-in feature in Identity. Create a page that takes inputs from user, then use controller to verify the information.  In the controller, create a readonly props of SigninManager if you want to login feature or UserManger, if its for registering user. Hope this help and sorry for any grammatical mistake as i am typing via phone.